# Scipy optimize return the innitial guess as solution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have an optimization problem, in which I need to solve for a vector X:

> E = O - X*H
>
> O and H are both known. Solve for X such that minimize the variance of E.

The code I wrote as follow:

```
H = np.matrix(df.ix[:,1:5]) # 61 by 4 matrix
O = np.matrix(df[fund]) # 1 by 61 matrix
#X = np.array([1,0,0,0]) # 1 by 4 matrix
def fitness(X, H=H, O=O):
    A = X*np.transpose(H) # 1 by 61 matrix
    E = O - A
    target = np.var(E, ddof=1)
    return target
cons = ({'type':'eq','fun': lambda X: sum(X)-1})
bnds = [(0, 1) for i in range(4)]
res = optimize.minimize(fitness, np.array([0,1,0,0]), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print res.x
```

The code keep returning the same innitial guess  as a solution. I also tried 'BFGS' method, which returning a wrong answer that violating the boundary constraints. I wonder if I did anything wrong with the script or the methods I used were not appropriate?

Comment: Its very likely that you problem closely related with svd-computation on the matrix H

Comment: I used Excel solving for the matrix X. When I plugged X in the script the fitness function give me exactly the Excel output.

Comment: You should always check that `res.success` is true, so that you know the solver converged (which is probably not the case if it returns the initial point).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what made the difference, but it seems like the 'TNC' method gave me what I'm looking for.